# What is Regtest?

Tags: monerod, regtest

I did not find much information about the regtest option for `monerod`. What does it actually do? What are the differences between `testnet` and `regtest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it actually do?

It runs in a "regression testing mode", which allows you to create a fake blockchain (i.e. it is not validated by other nodes), useful only for development and testing.

> What are the differences between testnet and regtest?

Testnet is a public p2p blockchain, other nodes on the testnet network validate transactions and blocks.

Comment: aah I see it. I got confused because I saw a tutorial about creating a private testnet and I thought that was the way to go if I wanted to create a fake blockchain. Thank you!

Comment: Really depends what you're trying to test. A private testnet still has use.

Comment: When should I use a private testnet or regtest?

Comment: Regtest is most useful for automation/integration testing. A private testnet for more thorough, real-world testing.